# async await not working as expected with react

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I am calling an async function inside `useEffect` hook in react as below.

```
const ab = async () => {
    console.log("start API");
    await callAPI();
    console.log("end API");
};

useEffect(() => {
    ab();
    console.log("calling");
}, []);
```

As the output first it will print start API then print calling and finally print end API. But what I need as the printing order is start API, end API, and calling. That's why I am using async await as well. But it's not working as expected. Any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's the point of using `await` – the execution is paused until `callAPI` is finished.

To achieve the order you want, don't use `await` and just let the code run asynchronously. This way, the synchronous code (`console.log('calling')`) will be ran without waiting for the asynchronous code (`callAPI()`) to finish.

EDIT: However, depending on your use case, the other answer would probably make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

For `async/await` to work , you'll have to `await` an asynchronous function.
Hence use the following code.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let helper = async () => {
      await ab(); // write await here
      console.log('calling');
    };
    helper();
  }, []);
```

Now the output would be:

```
Start API
End API
calling
```